# faster way of finding max/min of a given column for each value of another column and then subset to those rows

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am currently doing the following on my data.table `dat` which is the most time taking part in my code.

```
dat[ , max_ts:= max(TS, na.rm = T), .(col_new)]
dat_new <- dat[TS == max_ts, ]
```

What I am doing above is that first I am finding maximum of `TS` for each value/category of column `col_new` and then keeping only those rows where that maximum `TS`occurs.

My objective is to achieve `dat_new`

I need to do the above for different data tables in a loop. (Here it is slightly difficult to cut time, so please don't suggest anything here)

I am looking to do above 2 steps in a little faster way. Is there any better and more efficient way to do the same?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

We can use `.I` to get the row index and subset the rows based on that.  It should be faster.

```
dat[dat[ , .I[which.max(TS)], .(col_new)]$V1]
```

Here, I am assuming that there are no ties for the `max`.  If there are, then

```
dat[dat[, .I[TS == max(TS, na.rm=TRUE)], .(col_new)]$V1]
```

Comment: would ordering it and taking the 'last' value offer any speed? `dat[ dat[order(TS), .I[.N], by = .(col_new)]$V1 ]` - I suppose this won't handle the `NA`s...

Comment: @Symbolix I think using `setorder` with `.I` would be faster.  But, if there are ties, then it will only get a single row for each 'col_new'

Comment: @akrun there will be ties in my case, but i want to keep only first case appearing for those cases. So, can you optimize your solution further using `setorder`as you mentioned.